# Telegram-API Ошибка при редактировании сообщения: Error editing message text: [400] Bad Request: message can't be edited

Tags: java, telegram, telegrambots

При получении сообщения хочу его отредактировать ботом. Exception вылетает при отправки сообщения в чате (личном или группе), бот админ. Помогите если сталкивались

```
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new Bot());

        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMsg(Message message) {
        EditMessageText editMessageText = new EditMessageText();
        editMessageText.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
        editMessageText.setMessageId(message.getMessageId());
        editMessageText.setText(message.getText() + "!!!");

        try {
            execute(editMessageText);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        Message message = update.getMessage();

        if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
            switch (message.getText()) {
                case "/help":
                    sendMsg(message);
                    break;
                default: sendMsg(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Сама ошибка (ссылается на `execute(editMessageText);`

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error editing message text: [400] Bad Request: message can't be edited
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.updatingmessages.EditMessageText.deserializeResponse(EditMessageText.java:169)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:689)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.AbsSender.execute(AbsSender.java:53)
    at zherikhov.Bot.sendMsg(Bot.java:49)
    at zherikhov.Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:66)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:309)
org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error editing message text: [400] Bad Request: message can't be edited
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.updatingmessages.EditMessageText.deserializeResponse(EditMessageText.java:169)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendApiMethod(DefaultAbsSender.java:689)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.AbsSender.execute(AbsSender.java:53)
    at zherikhov.Bot.sendMsg(Bot.java:49)
    at zherikhov.Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:66)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:309)
```

Comment: я понимаю, что мой switch-case выглядит максимально странно, но сейчас суть не в этом

Comment: Попробовал, та же библиотека от rubenlagus (telegrambots версии 4.7).  
Получил такой же Exception.

Comment: @AlekPo причина в том, что телеграм блокируется на территории РФ, копайте в эту область

Comment: Cпасибо. Да, я это учел.  
Я пытался повторить вашу ошибку, как я её понял - Редактирование ботом полученного сообщения. Что я сделал - отправил боту сообщение, чтобы бот его отредактировал. И на этапе редактирования полученного сообщения получил Exception - "message can't be edited".  
Вы решили эту проблему?

Comment: @AlekPo ну как я понял, редактировать нельзя сообщения чужие, только свои, это так же как и у обычного юзера админа, ты можешь удалять чужое, но не редактировать

Answer (score 1):

Бот может редактировать только свои сообщения

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1248094/edit) для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

В моем случае я пытался отредачить/заменить стикер, но это не работало (логично), т.к. у него текста нет)
В итоге, я удалил стикер по id и просто отправил новое сообщение.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).